# Dont know how to set headers

Tags: email, header, prestashop

Could someone help me to set headers to this function. I bought Prestashop module to ask question on product page. But email are sent back to admin email. I know i need to set headers to respond to email given by user.

```
product = new Product(Tools::getValue('ip_product_id'), true, $id_language, $id_shop);
$sql = 'SELECT email FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'contact` WHERE id_contact = ' . (int) (Configuration::get('IP_ASK_ABOUT_PRODUCT_MAIL'));
$mail = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS($sql);   

if (Mail::Send((int)$id_language, 
                'ask', 
                Mail::l('Pytanie o produkt', (int)$id_language), 
            array(
        '{message}' => Tools::getValue('message'),
        '{mail}' => Tools::getValue('ip_ask_about_product_email'),
        '{name}' => Tools::getValue('ip_ask_about_product_name'),
        '{phone}' => Tools::getValue('ip_ask_about_product_phone'),
        '{id_product}' => $product->id,
        '{product_name}' => $product->name), 
            $mail[0]["email"], 
            null, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null, 
            dirname(__FILE__) . '/mails/'
    ))
{
```

Answer (score 0):

The option you are looking for is `ReplyTo`. This is the last parameter of function `Mail::Send`. Your code must look like this:

```
Mail::Send((int)$id_language, 
                'ask', 
                Mail::l('Pytanie o produkt', (int)$id_language), 
            array(
        '{message}' => Tools::getValue('message'),
        '{mail}' => Tools::getValue('ip_ask_about_product_email'),
        '{name}' => Tools::getValue('ip_ask_about_product_name'),
        '{phone}' => Tools::getValue('ip_ask_about_product_phone'),
        '{id_product}' => $product->id,
        '{product_name}' => $product->name), 
            $mail[0]["email"], 
            null, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null, 
            dirname(__FILE__) . '/mails/',

            false,
            null,
            null,
            $mail[0]["email"] /*or the email you want to reply to*/
    )
```

Good luck